# Recursively Invoking Lambda from Cloudwatch Scheduled Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to get a lambda function (call is LambdaA) to invoke itself when certain conditions are met. LambdaA is initially started using CloudWatch on a 1 minute recurring schedule. Then, when certain conditions are met I want that lambda to call itself (the reason for this primarily is because of the 5 minute timeout limit on lambda functions).

I'm invoking like:

```
InvokeRequest request = new InvokeRequest
        {
            FunctionName = "MyLambdaFunction"
        };

InvokeResponse invokeResult = client.InvokeAsync(request).Result;
```

The result is giving a successful 200 response but a new LambdaA isn't being kicked off.

LambdaA's role has full Lambda access in IAM and is successfully invoking a separate lambda (LambdaB) non recursively. FYI, LambdaB isn't scheduled by CloudWatch but is invoked by LambdaA. Both LambdaA and LambdaB are all in the same region.

Any ideas when it's not working?

Comment: Which language SDK are you using?

Comment: Updated tags with C#

Comment: Looks like v2 of the C# SDK. Presumably you've verified that the child Lambda did not actually run, using CloudWatch Logs (in case it errored out). The InvokeAsync(InvokeAsyncRequest) method is deprecated so you might want to try Invoke(InvokeRequest) with an InvocationType of Event. Also, interestingly but not necessarily relevant, the docs say that InvokeAsyncResponse will have a 202 Status upon success, not 200.

Comment: The code is in a .netcore v2 project and I'm using the latest stable version of Amazon.Lambda.Core(1.0.0) and AWSSDK.Lambda(3.3.12.2).
Yes, I verified via logging that the child lambda is not being created. I even added a Guid to the payload just to make sure.
Invoke(request) doesn't appear to be an option in AmazonLambdaClient.

Comment: Does the Lambda itself actually have permission to invoke Lambda? I presume so or it would immediately fail with a 403 (rather than immediately succeed with 2xx and async fail with 403).

Comment: Yes it does have permission (and it's returning a 200 status rather than 202).